# .NET HttpContext.User returning wrong type of object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security

I have a web application developed in VS using C# with MVC and I have a custom role provider. This has been working successfully for several years. When needed the roles are checked using:

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "admin, dataPerinatal, perinatalAllCases")]
public ActionResult PerinatalDataEntrySummary()
{
    IPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User;
    bool isAdmin = false;
    bool canViewAll = false;
    if (principal.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        isAdmin = true;
    }
    else if (principal.IsInRole("perinatalAllCases"))
    {
        canViewAll = true;
    }
    // ....
}
```

This returns `principal` as an object of type `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal`.

*This works with no problem.*

However, I have just added a *new* method within the *same* controller, and use identical code to get the `principal`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FindCaseFromID(string nIMACHCaseID, string mBRRACECaseID)
{

    principal = HttpContext.User

    bool canViewAll = false;
    if (principal.IsInRole("perinatalAllCases")) 
    { canViewAll = true; }
     // ....
}
```

But, this returns `principal` as an object of type `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal`. This uses `AspNetSqlRoleProvider` and results in the following problems:

1. The application generates a 'cannot find SQL server' error on systems without an SQL Express server installed
2. Where SQL Express Server is installed the `IsInRole` always returns `false`.

How can I ensure that every instance of `HttpContext.User` returns the type of object I require. Why is the second instance returning a different object type when everything else seems to be the same?

Comment: RolePrincipal is created if you have a role provider configured in your web.config. Is this the case?

Comment: No, it is not in web.config but is a custom provider. As I say in the question, it works apart from the new method.

Comment: Well, can you show the method that works, and the method that doesn't?  Are you using areas?

Comment: Thanks Brendan, code now added. Yes, I am using areas.

Comment: How are you plugging the custom role provider? With forms auth and a custom role provider, you should **always** get a RolePrincipal.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that pointed me in the right direction. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be a simple code error. All my controllers have a custom attribute`[CustomAuthorize]` for the whole controller.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class MyController : Controller
```

which creates `HttpContext.User` in the attribute class.

The initial method had the attribute include a role check (see above) however the attribute was missing from the class declaration as a whole and so the second method used the default role provider . Once I added the attribute the problem disappeared.